# Getting N minimal contiguous blocks in an array of numbers

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm currently working on the following problem:

Given an array of M positive numbers, I need to get N blocks of contiguous numbers with some given length. For example, when I have the array:

6 9 3 2 8 1 6 9 7

When I need to find one block of length 3, the solution is [3,2,8] which has a total minimal sum of 13. When I need to find two blocks, the algorithm should give [3,2,8] and [1,6,9] since the sum of all elements in these blocks is minimal (29). It is given that the length of the sequence is always strictly larger than N times the length of a block (so there is always a solution).

I think this problem is solvable by using DP but I currently can't see how. I'm struggling to find a recurrent relation between the subproblems. Could anyone give me a hand here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can find the first one in linear time. Just change numbers from `n` to `-n` and then apply the [standard algorithm for maximum subarray sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem). As for two: the sub-arrays can have intersections?

Comment: I'm confused as to the problem definition. When you are finding two blocks, why do you have to get [3,2,8] and [1,6,9] instead of [6,9,7] or [9,3,2], or another? What's the restriction here?

Comment: Can your blocks overlap?

Comment: @Baz1nga I've been thinking about the problem but I can't come to a good solution yet. I've thought about a greedy approach, however, that would not work since it's possible that I have to shift an already placed block when I have to place another block.

Comment: @icepack the block's can't overlap

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Calculate the sum of each block with the given length, and record them with the initial index. This can be done by a complexity of `O(n)`. So you get a list like:

   ```
   index    sum
   0        18
   1        14
   2        13
   ...      ...
   ```
2. Due to the objective blocks could not overlap with each other, so each difference of their indexes can not be less than the given length. So you need to apply a simple dynamic planning algorithm on the list you got.

   if the block length is `l`, list length is `n`(say the list `S[n]`), and you want to find `m` blocks, then the

   `F(n,m,l) = min { F(n-i-l,m-1,l) + S[n-i] }  (for i = 0 ~ n-(m-1)*l)`

The complexity of this step is `O(nm)` where `m` is how many blocks you want.

Finally the complexity is `O(nm)`. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I will try to implement this and let you know if it worked or not :)

Comment: @Devos50 tip for the DP: when finding 3 minimal 3-number blocks in a 10-number list, firstly find (2 minimal blocks in the first 7 numbers of the list) + (the last 3 numbers), and (2 minimal blocks in the first 6 numbers) + (the 6~9 numbers), etc.